# Change subcategory parent in Magento through admin panel

Tags: php, magento

Is it possible to change subcategory parent through admin panel, database etc.?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [Magento](http://magento.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have parent and child category like

- A

  - a1
  - a2
  - a3
- B

  - b1
  - b2
  - b3
- C

If you want b2 under "A" Use just drag b2 and drop b2 under "A".

Answer (score 1):

its so easy, just drag and drop

> **your category list**

[image: 1]

> **pick your category and start dragging**

[image: 2]

> **drop your category for which you want it to be child of**

[image: 3]

> **magento will automatically update its parent category**

[image: 4]